# Result of applying an 'if' dependant function on itself?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, relations

I have this function
$$h(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x < 0
\end{cases}$$
and I was wondering if I apply this function to itself $h \circ h$, can I just say the resulting function would be $h$? Seeing as they are both dependent on passing the same 'if' statement. If not, could you please help steer me in the right path? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

$$
h(h(x))
=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } h(x) \geq 0\\
0 & \text{ if } h(x) < 0
\end{cases}
 $$
But $h(x)$ is never negative. Thus the second case does not occur, which means $h(h(x))=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Aww ok I get it now! That's a lot simpler than I thought I was trying to join the functions without even thinking about that you will always get a positive number from the first one! Thanks, silly mistake!